# How do I use Correlation in WF4 StateFlow (Platform Update 1)

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, correlation, stateflow

I have a WF Service (CustomerProvisioningService) that receives a Request message and immediately runs up a StateFlow (CustomerProvisioningStateFlow) and which is marked as CanCreateInstance.

The first State in the flow has a Sequential flow as its Entry activity which is a long running work flow with its own Send and ReceiveReply pattern to call out and receive extra information(ProvisionCustomerActivityFlow). This workflow CanCreateInstance too.

I presume for the sequential flow I need to manage correlation based on Content (CustomerId) and in this way I can identify the persisted workflow in the underlying AppFabric sql persistence.

Subsequently I have other operations in the StateFlow which are represented by WCF Service calls similar to :

```
SuspendCustomer(string customerId)
```

I am assuming that I need to pick up the correct StateFlow instance by correlating with the CustomerId in the StateFlow but I can find no way to apply Correlation in the StateFlow, neither by adding CorrelationInitializers nor referencing a local CorrelationHandle variable.

Now I am questioning if I need correlation on the StateFlow and if so how do I do it? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Many thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup request message correlation to route messages to the same workflow instance. I have an example on my blog [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/04/28/workflow-receive-activity-and-message-correlation.aspx) about how to set this up. The example uses a Sequence but the process is the same with a state machine.

Comment: Maurice, thanks for your reply and sorry for taking so long to respond. This is part of the answer (an important one) but the other part was that I needed to be very careful about setting the correlization on the embedded Receive events. Also, the final bit was to make the workflow service call the State flow directly asnd not use a sequence flow to call it. When I get a chance I am gfoing to try to document it